# split json using apache camel

Tags: java, json, apache-camel

I have `json` that has this format

```
{
   "info": "private_info_id",
   "items": [
       { "itemId": "1", "itemName": "Custom item 1" },
       { "itemId": "2", "itemName": "Custom item 2" }
   ]
}
```

I create message object

```
class MessageObject {
    String requestId;
    String json;
}
```

And send it to `messageObjectEndpoint`.And later consume it.

```
<route>
    <from ref="messageObjectEndpoint"/>
    <bean ref="messageConsumer"/>
</route>
```

I want to split it into smaller messages, send them and aggregate on receive. How to do that?

As far as I understand `camel` allows splitting messages if the `json` looks like this

```
[{ ... }, { ... }]
```

But as I have the additional data - `info`, `items` fields instead of a simple array - is it possible to split it with additional data and then aggregate again?

Comment: If you have an array of json object, you can split it. I know, it can be done using jackson as long as you have a model.

Comment: so you propose to split messages manually and then aggregate it using camel?

Comment: Yes, something like this, say you have Item[] array object where Item is a class, you can split as per your need.

Comment: but how then I aggregate them later? I mean for example I have a json with 100 items, I create 5 messages with 20 items. All of them will have for example same `requestId`. How to aggregate them later? AFter alll consumer won't know how many messages were sent...

Comment: you can have your own method doing the split ie: `split(ExpressionBuilder.beanExpression(new MyClassThatSplit(), "myMethod"), new MyAggregationStrategy())` or you can specify the `jsonpath` https://camel.apache.org/jsonpath.html